# ImportError: cannot import name 'NUMPY' from 'openpyxl.compat.numbers'

Tags: python, numpy, openpyxl

Successfully installed `openpyxl` with no errors

When I try to initialize with

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
```

I get the following import error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    from openpyxl import Workbook
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/openpyxl/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from openpyxl.compat.numbers import NUMPY
ImportError: cannot import name 'NUMPY' from 'openpyxl.compat.numbers' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/openpyxl/compat/numbers.py)
```

I did a completely new install of python 3.12.0 and it seems like the `openpyxl` has not been updated to work with 3.12.0.

When I mess with the source code in the `openpyxl` module I can get it to go the next step of the import. But I don't really want to go that route.

Any and all assistance would be great appreciated

Comment: it should be `numpy`, not `NUMPY`. You may have to fix source code,. And maybe you would have to send this error to author of `openpyxl`

Comment: @furas looking at the [code](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/blob/branch/3.1/openpyxl/compat/numbers.py) it would seem like `NUMPY` is a boolean specifying whether Numpy could be imported.

Comment: Would be good to know what you installed!  The developers of that package seem to have been actively testing against Python 3.12 since January

Comment: As mentioned it was a brand new install of python 3.12 on a new Mac and the used pip to install openpyxl 3.1.2.  I was able to eventually get it to work but required a lot of mods to the various __init__,py scripts. Perhaps the devs need to try it on a completely new install like I did, because openpyxl 3.1.2 did not install smoothly unti I modified the scripts.

Comment: @user2320194 It sounds like you're used to dealing with commercial software, but openpyxl is an open source package.  Hence it's up to users, like you, to contribute to it to keep the project going if you want it to work.  Maybe you could report an issue to the project directly?

Comment: I started doing open source with punch cards so that is definitely not new to me. There's only one me and thousands of open source packages, hopefully you can appreciate the dilemma.